# Why wont computers on LAN show up on "Network" in Windows Explorer?

Tags: networking, windows-8, windows-10, remote-desktop

I have 2 desktop computers. One on ethernet and one on wifi. One running Windows 10, one running Windows 8.

Both machines have network discovery on. Both have RDP enabled.

But when I go to the network tab on either machines, it wont show the computers. I remember I used to be able to go on computer A, open network and then see my Computer B listed there and I would be able to right click on it and remote connect to it. Why cant I now? They werent apart of a home group. Just on the same LAN.

I can ping the computer just fine. But it wont show up on network discovery or rdp

Comment: is your wifi provided via a Router or an AP (eg are the devices on the same IP network)? Does the wifi router/ap implement a Client Isolation feature or NAT?

Answer (score 0):

Add exception in firewall for rdp,

> Go to Windows Firewall => Allow a program or feature through Windows Firewall => Change settings => Allowed programs and features =>

[image]